# Automating the maintenance of Athena views

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am currently working on creating a data lake where we can compile, combine and analysis multiple data sets in S3.

I am using Athena and Quicksight as a central part of this to be able to quickly query and explore the data.  To make things easier in Quicksight for end-users, I am creating many Athena views that do some basic transformation and aggregations.

I would like to be able to source control my views and create some automation around them so that we can have a code-driven approach and not rely on users manually updating views and running DDL to update the definitions.

There does not seem to be any support in Cloudformation for Athena views.

My current approach would be to just save the `create or replace view as ...` DDL in an .sql file in source control and then create some sort of script that runs the DDL so it could be made part of a continuous integration solution.

Anyone have any other experience with automation and CI for Athena views?

Comment: Have you had any luck on this problem?  I just setup some tables in Athena via AWS Glue.  The Glue crawler is actually awesome, but II too want to store this as IaC, but haven't found a good method yet either.

Comment: I haven’t looked if there was any recent new features around this but we ended up just storing our view definitions as sql files in source control.  I couldn’t find a way via Cloudformation to automate the deployment but it is possible to use this files and the AWS CLI as part of your automation if you are using something like terraform. If you think it’s a good question, please upvote so it gets more attention

Comment: Cool, I upvoted it.  We are working on a UI for Athena in the app I built, Commandeer.  We have built a few plugins for Serverless and Ansible, so this might go on our todo list as well.

Comment: Just faced this challenge myself. Not ideal, but I upload my ddl to s3 via TF. Lambda then compares views on the db against files in s3. Where it detects a new ddl, or newer version, executes the ddl to drop/replace/create.  Would prefer a solid & supported tool to do this though, I didn't come to AWS to carry the burden of maintaing things like this that will never be perfect in house.

Answer (score 3):

Long time since OP posted, but here goes a bash script to do just that. You can use this script on CI of your choice.

This script assumes that you have a directory with all your .sql files definition for the views. Within that directory there is a .env file to make some deploy time replacements of shell envs.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export VIEWS_DIRECTORY="views"
export DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT="dev"
export ENV_FILENAME="views.env"
export OUTPUT_BUCKET="your-bucket-name-$DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT"
export OUTPUT_PREFIX="your-prefix"
export AWS_PROFILE="your-profile"

cd $VIEWS_DIRECTORY
# Create final .env file with any shell env replaced
env_file=".env"
envsubst < $ENV_FILENAME > $env_file

# Export variables in .env as shell environment variables
export $(grep -v '^#' ./$env_file | xargs)

# Loop through all SQL files replacing env variables and pushing to AWS
FILES="*.sql"
for view_file in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $view_file file..."
  # Replacing env variables in query file
  envsubst < $view_file > query.sql
  # Running query via AWS CLI
  query=$(<query.sql) \
    && query_execution_id=$(aws athena start-query-execution \
    --query-string  "$query" \
    --result-configuration "OutputLocation=s3://${OUTPUT_BUCKET}/${OUTPUT_PREFIX}" \
    --profile $AWS_PROFILE \
    | jq -r '.QueryExecutionId')
  # Checking for query completion successfully
  echo "Query executionID: $query_execution_id"
  while :
    do
    query_state=$(aws athena get-query-execution \
        --query-execution-id $query_execution_id \
        --profile $AWS_PROFILE \
        | jq '.QueryExecution.Status.State')
    echo "Query state: $query_state"
    if [[ "$query_state" == '"SUCCEEDED"' ]]; then
        echo "Query ran successfully"
        break
    elif [[ "$query_state" == '"FAILED"' ]]; then
        echo "Query failed with ExecutionID: $query_execution_id"
        exit 1
    elif [ -z "$query_state" ]; then
        echo "Unexpected error. Terminating routine."
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Waiting for query to finish running..."
        sleep 1
    fi

    done

done
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use AWS Glue

> **When Should I Use AWS Glue?**
>
> You can use AWS Glue to build a data warehouse to organize, cleanse,
>   validate, and format data. You can transform and move AWS Cloud data
>   into your data store. You can also load data from disparate sources
>   into your data warehouse for regular reporting and analysis. By
>   storing it in a data warehouse, you integrate information from
>   different parts of your business and provide a common source of data
>   for decision making.
>
> AWS Glue simplifies many tasks when you are building a data warehouse:
>
> - Discovers and catalogs metadata about your data stores into a central catalog.
> - You can process semi-structured data, such as clickstream or process logs.
> - Populates the AWS Glue Data Catalog with table definitions from scheduled crawler programs. Crawlers call classifier logic to infer
>     the schema, format, and data types of your data. This metadata is
>     stored as tables in the AWS Glue Data Catalog and used in the
>     authoring process of your ETL jobs.
> - Generates ETL scripts to transform, flatten, and enrich your data from source to target.
> - Detects schema changes and adapts based on your preferences.
> - Triggers your ETL jobs based on a schedule or event. You can initiate jobs automatically to move your data into your data
>     warehouse. Triggers can be used to create a dependency flow between
>     jobs.
> - Gathers runtime metrics to monitor the activities of your data warehouse.
> - Handles errors and retries automatically.
> - Scales resources, as needed, to run your jobs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/what-is-glue.html

Comment: I do use Glue to crawl my original datasets and get them into Athena.  The glue data  catalog automatically recognizes views as tables in the catalog for use with other things like ETL jobs.   I don't see how Glue helps with the source control or automation of Athena views.

Comment: Sorry if you cannot understand what I posted. Glue can run ETL jobs including updating views.

Comment: Glue is a terrible tool, stay away from it. Glue can't do what the OP is asking.

Comment: And we should just take your word for it. I posted a link that proves otherwise.